# Variable empty after assigning value from database to it

Tags: java, mysql, database, swing, variables

I am running a query to return the `Course_Id`that is associated with the `Course_Name` that is selected using a JComboBox (`slcCourse`) in a form. The query seems to be correct, at least I think so, and the JComboBox returns the correct `Course_Name` from the table. When I try to assign the value returned, which should be the `Course_Id` from the database table, in a global or local variable and output it using JOptionPane that variable, it is empty. I am not sure why it is not being assigned to the variable and any help would be much appreciated.

The connection to the database works fine because I have already inserted records in the same class using the connection details. So the problem does not lie there.

Here is the code:

```java
public void courseIdentifier()
    {
        Connection conDBase = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet r = null;

        try
        {
            conDBase = getConnection();
            stmt = conDBase.createStatement();
            String courseSql = "SELECT Course_Id FROM a_courses WHERE Course_Name = '" 
                                    + slcCourse.getSelectedItem() + "';";
            r = stmt.executeQuery(courseSql);

            String s = r.getString("Course_Id");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, s);
            conDBase.close();
        }
        catch(SQLException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

In case you wanted to see the connection details, here it is:

```java
public class ConnectionDetails
{
    private static final String username = "root";
    private static final String password = "root";
    private static final String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/assignment?autoReconnect=true";

    public static String getUsername()
    {
        return username;
    }

    public static String getPassword()
    {
        return password;
    }

    public static String getDriver()
    {
        return driver;
    }

    public static String getUrl()
    {
        return url;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should call `next()` on the ResultSet before getting values from it :

```
if (r.next()) {
    String s = r.getString("Course_Id");
}
```

Also, you might want to do something with the `String` you read from the `ResultSet`. Perhaps return it to the caller of the method.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know it was that simple.
What I'm going to do is assign the returned value to a global variable so that I can use it in another method to run a different query to add that course_id to another table.